# KeyError when Deploying project to google cloud

Tags: python, django, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, conda

I'm trying to deploy my django+postgreSQL project to GCP by following this guide https://codeburst.io/beginners-guide-to-deploying-a-django-postgresql-project-on-google-cloud-s-flexible-app-engine-e3357b601b91 I came to the point where I was going to write this command "./manage.py collectstatic" but I get a KeyError. I think it is because I'm not using conda but instead I'm using venv(?).

This is my error:

> File "C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\settings.py", line 12, in 
> DEBUG = os.environ['DEBUG'] =='True'   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\os.py",
> line 681, in **getitem**
> raise KeyError(key) from None KeyError: 'DEBUG'

Is there a way to follow the guide without using conda? I'm very new to this so I'm sorry if my explaining is bad.

Comment: You get the key error here: `os.environ['DEBUG']`, it means there is no environment variable with the key `DEBUG`.

Comment: Did you set the DEBUG environment variable somewhere? What is happening it’s trying to retrieve the environment variable (DEBUG) in the bool comparison and it’s not set hence the KeyError. I can see in the app.yaml example it is set, but haven’t read through the instructions so not surely exactly where you’re seeing the error.

Comment: `app.yaml` would set the environment variables in google cloud but not locally. You need to set environment variables for them locally if you want to run them.

Comment: In app.yaml I have set DEBUG: 'False' and in settings.py I have set DEBUG = os.environ['DEBUG'] =='True'. Is there something wrong with doing that?